# UI Button doesnt perform action till 2nd time you press

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

i have a button on my `UITabBar` (custom) and animations when the button is clicked doesn't perform until you press it twice. A print statement that i used print's on the first try though so i'm not sure why it doesn't perform the animations on the first try. Here is my code:

```
func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "play") {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "playbutton2"), for: .normal)
            self.button2.frame = CGRect(x: self.tabBar.center.x, y: self.tabBar.center.y - 100,  width: self.buttonimage.size.width, height: self.buttonimage.size.height)
            self.view3.alpha = 0.6
        })
    } else {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play"), for: .normal)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
            self.button2.center = self.button.center
            self.view3.alpha = 0
        })
    }

    print("Middle Button was just pressed!")
}
```

I am running this function through a target like so in `viewWillAppear`:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: is it happening only very first time or for all times?

Comment: @DharmbirSingh only the first time, soon as i press it again it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not set image on button in xib so set your image in view did load like

hope it will work

```
button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: @thelegendary3 actually it is going else part very first time i think you haven't set image on button in xib and then it will come on if part .. hope you can understand :)

Comment: @thelegendary3 If you wanna learn mobile tech (iOS & Android) kindly subscribe my youtube channel **https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA5HRmlkT7bqbO56EIlT0UQ**